# Windows - how to detect another system status

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, port

i have opened PORT 8003 in my Windows Client system firewall as inbound and outbound rule to allow connection by following Steps available [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/block-open-port-windows-8-firewall).

When i check back PORT 8003 connection using below python program to test back whether its actually enabled, but i still get port closed message. is there anything i am doing wrong?

My intention is to identify remote client is reachable, i expect client system reboot during test. 
**Note:****Unable to use PING as when firewall enabled PING requests are blocked.**

netstat -a does not show 8003 in its listening list.

Program i used to scan port:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server = 'IPHERE'

def PortScanner(port):
    try:
        s.connect((server,port))
        return True
    except:
        return False

for x in range(8003,8006):
    if PortScanner(x):
        print("Port is open",x)
    else:
        print("port is Closed",x)
```

Comment: Having the port open in your Windows client doesn't mean that other devices in the network must follow.

Comment: Why would the system reboot? Why would it do anything?

Comment: @MichaelBay what is the better way to detect windows  system is reachable ... Ping I cannot keep as firewall blocks that request ..

Comment: @davidgo I am applying few configuration and to apply these configuration system will reboot automatically

Comment: Well, if there's a firewall it must also allow the required port. This is exactly what was implicit in my first comment.

Comment: @MichaelBay Got It is there any way i can detect my client system?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details on what the service on (TCP?) port 8003 is supposed to do.

To the core question "Windows - how to detect another system status":

- With a system in your local subnet, you can check for successful ARP resolution (e.g. for `192.168.37.25`), regardless of firewall settings

  - `ping 192.168.37.25`
  - `arp -a 192.168.37.25`
- For a remote system (where you need to cross a router), you need some kind of IP service you're allowed to talk to and get an answer from. This may be `ping`, `net view`, ...
- With neither, there's no way to find out.